# Laravel store session in cookie

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel-4, session-cookies

I have a website where the front page contains a search form with several fields.

When the user performs a search, I make an ajax call to a function in a controller.

Basically, when the user clicks on the submit button, I send an ajax call via post to:

```
Route::post('/search', 'SearchController@general');
```

Then, in the `SearchController` class, in the function `general`, I store the values received in a session variable which is an object:

```
Session::get("search")->language = Input::get("language");
Session::get("search")->category = Input::get("category");
//I'm using examples, not the real variables names
```

After updating the session variable, in fact, right after the code snippet shown above, I create (or override) a cookie storing the session values:

```
Cookie::queue("mysite_search", json_encode(Session::get("search")));
```

And after that operation, I perform the search query and send the results, etc.

All that work fine, but I'm not getting back the values in the cookie. Let me explain myself.

As soon as the front page of my website is opened, I perform an action like this:

```
if (!Session::has("search")) {

        //check for a cookie
        $search = Cookie::get('mysite_search');

        if($search) Session::put("search", json_decode($search));
        else {
             $search = new stdClass();
             $search->language = "any";
             $search->category = "any";
             Session::put("search", $search);
        }

}
```

That seems to be always failing `if($search)` is always returning `false`, and as a result, my session variable `search` has always its properties `language` and `category` populated with the value `any`. (Again: I'm using examples, not the real variables names).

So, I would like to know what is happening here and how I could achieve what I'm intending to do.

I tried to put `Session::put("search", json_decode($search));` right after `$search = Cookie::get('mysite_search');` removing all the `if else` block, and that throws an error (the ajax call returns an error) so the whole thing is failling at some point, when storing the object in the cookie or when retieving it.

Or could also be something else. I don't know. That's why I'm here. Thanks for reading such a long question.

Comment: You're using the session getter function, this is for retrieving the the session data, not setting it. Laravel 4 uses the `Session::put('key', 'value');` syntax for setting session variables.

Comment: @Joe I don't get what you're saying. I'm putting the session: ``Session::put("search", json_decode($search));``. Later I'm overrriding some properties of the session like: ``Session::get("search")->language = Input::get("language");`` which is working perfectly (the session variable get that especific property overriden). The problem is json_encode and json_decode. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Quote: "I tried to put Session::put("search", json_decode($search)); right after $search = Cookie::get('mysite_search'); removing all the if else block, and that throws an error (the ajax call returns an error) so the whole thing is failling at some point, when storing the object in the cookie or when retieving it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. This is what was going on.

The problem was this:

```
Cookie::queue("mysite_search", json_encode(Session::get("search")));
```

Before having it that way I had this:

```
Cookie::forever("mysite_search", json_encode(Session::get("search")));
```

But for some reason, that approach with `forever` wasn't creating any cookie, so I swichted to `queue` (this is **Laravel 4.2**). But `queue` needs a third parameter with the expiration time. So, what was really going on is that the cookie was being deleted after closing the browser (I also have the `session.php` in `app/config` folder set to `'lifetime' => 0` and `'expire_on_close' => true` which is exactly what I want).

In simple words, I set the expiration time to forever (5 years) this way:

```
Cookie::queue("mysite_search", json_encode(Session::get("search")), 2592000);
```

And now it seems to be working fine after testing it.